# vba counter that takes value from different cell on each loop

Tags: vba

I have solved this problem myself thanks to the people who offered help

I have an if statement which relies on a counter, I am taking the value of the counter from cell "B3" and the code works fine as it is.
However each time I loop through the program I need the counter to take it's value from a different cell.
so for example loop 1 read value from "B3"
loop 2 read value from "C3"
next "D3" and so on across the sheet
keep going until it reaches a an empty cell
I have dim c as integer
and for c= 2 to 26 to take me to the 26th column
but I am not sure how to get it to increment each time the loop starts. can anyone help with this? I can post the full code I am using at the moment if that will help the understanding of the question

```
Public Sub copyX()
Dim listofcells As Range
Dim currentname As String
Dim foundrow As Integer
Dim foundcolumn As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer

For i = 2 To 26

    Sheets("Availability").Activate
    counter = Range("b3")
    Sheets("Availability").Range("a2").Select
    If Not Sheets("Availability").Cells(2, i) = "" Then
        Sheets("Availability").Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, i).End(xlDown)).Select
    Else
        GoTo skip:  'If the column has no data then skip to next column
    End If
    Set listofcells = Selection

    Sheets("allocation").Activate
    Range("a2").Select


    For Each singlecell In listofcells
            If counter > 0 Then
            If singlecell = "Available" Then
            foundcolumn = singlecell.Column 'record the column number where "Available" was found
            currentname = Sheets("availability").Range("A" & singlecell.Row) 'record the name of the person in the row where "Available" was found
            Set foundName = Sheets("allocation").Range("A:A").Find(What:=currentname, LookIn:=xlValues) 'find the persons name in "Allocation" sheet
            foundrow = foundName.Row
            Sheets("allocation").Cells(foundrow, foundcolumn) = "X" 'place yes in the same cell as it appeared in "Availability" sheet
            counter = counter - 1
            End If
        End If

    Next singlecell

skip:
Next i

End Sub
```

I have come up with the following code which does go through the cells and get their value, the problem is I can not get a for next loop to work inside another for next loop.
Set counterrange = Range("b3:Z3")
    For Each cell In counterrange
    Next cell

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Hi there I have added my code for you to look at

Comment: in which line do you want to get dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

Try with this concept ...

modify your code to

```
Dim k as Integer

k=3;

counter =Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(3, k)).Value    // through this you will get dynamic counter value like B3,D3,E3.,,,,

if(counter !="")
{
//execute some code
}
k=k+1;
```

Comment: Sorry no I haven't as I can not understand what it is doing or where I add it into my code. My apologies I am very new to VBA and am really on a steep learning curve here

Comment: You are hard coded counter range as("b3"). so you will not get ("c3,d3,...") so change counter code as i mentioned and through loop increment it..